# Introspector.getBeanInfo, setters with property subclasses and Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, javabeans, introspection

I fought a strange bug in a program and finally found a behavioural change of Introspector.getBeanInfo. Take the following demonstration programm:

```
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;

class MyBean {
  private Integer nr;
  public Number getNr() { return nr; }
  public void setNr(Integer nrx) { nr=nrx; }
}

public class IntrospectorTester {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
    for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor:
           Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyBean.class,Object.class)
           .getPropertyDescriptors())
      System.out.println(descriptor);
  }
}
```

Note that the test bean has a very special design as the getter returns a more general type (*Number*) than the setter requests (*Integer*).

When you run this on Java 7, the (manually pretty-printed) output is this:

```
1.7.0_45
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor[
  name=nr;
  propertyType=class java.lang.Number;
  readMethod=public java.lang.Number MyBean.getNr()
]
```

On Java 8, however, we get this:

```
1.8.0_60
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor[
  name=nr;
  propertyType=class java.lang.Number;
  readMethod=public java.lang.Number MyBean.getNr();
  writeMethod=public void MyBean.setNr(java.lang.Integer)
]
```

So, the Java 8 incarnation of **Introspector.getBeanInfo()** finds the setter method even though it takes a *subtype* of the property type as parameter.

Ok, I know. Intermixing types of bean properties and their element methods  this way is wrong and a call for trouble. The code in question is old and not mine. Anyway, does anyone have further information *why* this behavioural change was made to the Introspector? I mean, actually the bean has been designed wrongly if you read the bean specification carefully (always same *ParameterType* for getter, setter, and field). So, *either* the setter should be completely ignored (as Java 7 does) *or* the whole property should be bound to the most specific type (Integer it is). Java 8's Introspector produces a quite weird mixture. Why?

Comment: No, assuming the most specific type would be entirely wrong, as the getter does not guaranty to produce that most specific type. Besides that, since you can have multiple setters with the same name and different parameter types, but can’t overload getters on the Java language level, using the getter to determine the property type is a natural choice.

Comment: Quick FYI, you can compare what changed between OpenJDK [Java 7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/beans/Introspector.java#Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods%28java.lang.Class%29) and [Java 8](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/beans/Introspector.java#Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods%28java.lang.Class%29). Notice that an `else` clause was added.

Comment: And I do not find the results weird. The Java Beans spec doesn't specify what should happen in this case so both behaviour are correct in that regard.